# Which is the best way to control the ASP.net output cache memory size in IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, outputcache

Someone here knows how to control the total possible amount of memory that ASP.net uses to maintain the output cache? I'm having some troubles and memory issues related to this and I want to limit the growth of the cache in my IIS 6 server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxCacheSize="1000" maxResponseSize="512000"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It was far away and its false, but as I remember, `web.config` has special section which can specify cache size. I forgot its name, but I'm 75% sure it present!

Comment: I did not understand... What is far away and false?

Comment: in Russia it means "I don't remember exactly"